# Springboot: How to reference a variable from Kubernetes secret

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have springboot2.4.0. I am trying to read a variable in K8s secret by using springboot @Value and application.properties but it doesn't work out. It can only print `localxyz` instead of `dXNlcg==`("user"). Anything I'm doing wrong?

My springboot property holder

```
@Component
@Getter
public class PropertyHolder {
    @Value("${secret.abc}")
    private String abc;
}
```

Application.properties

```
secret.abc=localxyz
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dev
secret.abc=${AAA}//Is this right?
```

secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret.abc
data:
  abc: dXNlcg==
```

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-ing-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-ing-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-ing-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: config-demo
        image: xxxxx
        env:      
        - name: SPRING_PROFILE
          value: dev
        - name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: spring-config
              key: dev-config.json
        - name: AAA # Is this just a arbitrary name?
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: secret.abc
              key: abc
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: Does this environment variable is available within the pod? You can `kubectl exec` to the pod and check it. Just to rule out kubernetes itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key-value in application.properties after the `#---` won't be read.(There could be a way to make it work but I don't know)

```
secret.abc=localxyz
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=dev
secret.abc=${AAA}//Is this right?
```

So in my application

```
@Value("${secret.abc}")
    private String abc;
```

will only read `secret.abc=localxyz`.
But by using `kubectl exec pod123 -- printenv` I do see `AAA` available. So the code need to be changed to

```
@Value("${AAA}")
    private String abc;
```

then it can read from the secret.

Answer (score 0):

AAA is not arbitrary. You will have to use this name in your application.properties to get the value as shown below

```
secret.abc=${AAA}
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-ing-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-ing-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-ing-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: config-demo
        image: xxxxx
        env:      
        - name: SPRING_PROFILE
          value: dev
        - name: SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: spring-config
              key: dev-config.json
        - name: AAA # Is this just a arbitrary name?
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: secretabc
              key: abc
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Also, your secretKeyRef name appears to be mismatching. Change to name: secretabc in your deployment.yaml. db-secret seems to be undefined

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry it was typo. I did use `secret.abc=${AAA}` but the app can only read `localxyz` when it got deployed. Anything you notice I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your secretKeyRef name appears to be mismatching. Change to name: secretabc in your deployment.yaml. db-secret seems to be undefined